# Procedural macro inside Syntactic macro error

Tags: rust, rust-macros

lets say I wan't to generate this with just syntactic macros:

```rust
struct Foo {
    bar: [Bar; 100],
    gee: [Gee; 100],
}
```

with just this macro call:

```rust
make_struct!(100; Bar, Gee);
```

The first and obvious problem is is that lowercase `bar`/`gee` which as far as I know is impossible to create on syntactic macros so I made a small utility proc macro.

```rust
use proc_macro::{Ident, Span, TokenTree, TokenStream};

/// Take identifier and return it lowercase
#[proc_macro]
pub fn lower(stream: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let tt = stream.into_iter().nth(0).unwrap();
    if let TokenTree::Ident(ident) = tt {
        dbg!(&ident);
        let new_ident = ident.to_string().to_lowercase();
        dbg!(&new_ident);
        TokenTree::Ident(
            Ident::new(&new_ident[..], Span::mixed_site())).into()
    } else {
        panic!("Invalid input to `lower` macro, just accepts one literal");
    }
}
```

Then how do I use this macro inside a syntactic macro? Because this works:

```rust
macro_rules! test {
    ($x:ident) => {
        let lower!($x) = 10;
    }
}

test!(Foo); // -> let foo = 10;
```

But this fails:

```rust
macro_rules! test {
    ($x:ident) => {
        struct Test { lower!($x) : [$x; 100] }
    }
}

test!(Foo); // -> (); ERROR
```

Is this a compiler error? or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you post the full error message that you're getting?

Comment: There are multriple issues, but the main thing is that the proc-macro is not expanded the right moment so it says that `lower!($x)` for example is not a valid identifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is that macro invocations are not allowed in arbitrary locations in the source code, but only certain contexts (like expressions and items).

There is a workaround, however, and it is already implemented by the [`paste`](https://docs.rs/paste/latest/paste/) library which does what your proc macro does as part of its main job of concatenating identifiers. The macro can be invoked from a larger context and process the tokens within it however it likes. With paste:

```rust
macro_rules! test {
    ($x:ident) => {
        paste::paste! {
            struct Test { [<$x:lower>] : [$x; 100] }
        }
    }
}
```

In use, the `paste!` macro by itself can be placed anywhere a macro invocation can, and it does nothing until it sees the token sequence `[< ... >]` telling it to process the tokens within those regions in particular. Thus `paste` bypasses the restriction on macro invocation positions.

Comment: I didn't wanted to process everything with proc macros because thats quite slow but it makes the job so thanks, if no one knows a way of doing it without full processing I'll mark this as the solution